# Flink how to discover all kafka partitions per key

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I using "keyby" in my data stream. i want flink discover all kafka partitions per key. 
I have 30 partition & 12 tasks. 
I "keyby" my data by user id. I think flink per task just discover specific 
kafka partition & i can not detect all data per user in one task.

Answer (score 0):

Flink generally doesn't make any association between the partitioning being done during stream processing via keyBy, and the partitioning that exists in your stream storage layer, in Kafka. If you use keyBy on the stream coming from a Kafka consumer, all of the events for each user will be processed together, regardless of what kafka partition they come from.

I don't understand what you are trying to do, but you can read about how Flink handles Kafka topic and partition discovery [in the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-topic-and-partition-discovery).